# Ajax / Javascript - Remove Links After 1 Link Has Been Clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I have the following script which fetches data (branch names) asynchronously via database:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pickup").on('keyup',function () {
        var key = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'modal/fetch_branch.php',
            type:'GET',
            data:'keyword='+key,
            beforeSend:function () {
                $("#results").slideUp('fast');
            },
            success:function (data) {
                $("#results").html(data);
                $("#results").slideDown('fast');
                // use `on` as elements are added dynamically
                $( "#results" ).on("click", "a", function() {
                // take `text` of a clicked element and set it as `#pickup` value
                 $( "#pickup" ).val( $( this ).text() );
                // return false to prevent default action
              return false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control empty" name="keyword" id="pickup" placeholder="&#xf041;"/>
```

Everything is working perfectly, When user clicks link the data (branch name) gets added to the `text input field`, which is exactly what needs to happen, however...

### My Problem

After user has clicked on desired link (branch name) I need the remaining links (data / branch names) to get removed...

[image]

As can be seen from above image Stellenbosch was selected, thus I need the other links to get removed...

Any advice how I can achieve the following greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

Here is the `fetch_branch.php` file as requested:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1 ) // so if we have 0 records acc. to keyword display no records found
{
    echo '<div id="item">Ah snap...! No results found :/</div>';
} else {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) //outputs the records
    {
        $branch = $row['location'];
        echo '<a style="cursor:pointer">'.$brach.'</a>';
        echo'<br />';
    }//while
}//else
}//if
```

Comment: Some html would be great

Comment: Sorry about that just added the `input field`

Comment: Please add the html for the links like Stellenbosch , Strand

Comment: Inside click handler, which btw shouldn't be set inside success callback nor nested inside keyup event, use `$( "#results a" ).not(this).remove();`

Comment: @user2181397 That gets fetched in a separate file via, PHP from DB, will update Now

Comment: `fetch_branch.php` looks like it has a few errors in it, or is that just a hurried retypo

Comment: I just typed it up, dont belief `fetch_branch.php`  is relevant to the question, then again I might be wrong

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee are you using `$("#results")` `div` to show only links?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `$(this).siblings().remove();` inside your click event. so your function should look like this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pickup").on('keyup',function () {
        var key = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'modal/fetch_branch.php',
            type:'GET',
            data:'keyword='+key,
            beforeSend:function () {
                $("#results").slideUp('fast');
            },
            success:function (data) {
                $("#results").html(data);
                $("#results").slideDown('fast');
                // use `on` as elements are added dynamically
                $( "#results" ).on("click", "a", function() {
                    // take `text` of a clicked element and set it as `#pickup` value
                    $( "#pickup" ).val( $( this ).text() );
                    //------------------
                    //only this line is newly added
                    //------------------
                    $(this).siblings().remove();
                    //------------------
                    // return false to prevent default action
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm making a different assumption from the other answers here, because I can't understand why you'd want to **remove** the other links in the dropdown, after clicking one!

> As can be seen from above image Stellenbosch was selected, thus I need the **other** links to get removed...

If that is indeed the case, you'll want to accept @acontell's answer.

However, if you'd like the clicked link to disappear from your list, you might try something like this in the click handler:

[image: Ex. 1]

```
$("#results").on("click", "a", function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $("#pickup").val($this.text());

    // Remove the linebreaks output by modal/fetch_branch.php
    $this.next('br').remove();

    // Remove the clicked <a> tag itself
    $this.remove();

    // return false to prevent default action
    return false;
});
```

In case you'd like the whole dropdown to disappear when clicked, do this: (which, I think is common, no?)

[image: Ex 2.]

```
$("#results").on("click", "a", function() {
    $("#pickup").val($(this).text());
    $("#results").slideUp();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

After selecting the item and setting the text to input add the following code snippet

```
 $(this).siblings().remove();
```

This removes all the sibling li s of the selected item

or

```
$( "#results a" ).not(this).remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, I think it could be done with a little modification to your code:

```
...
success:function (data) {
    $("#results").html(data);
    $("#results").slideDown('fast');
    // use `on` as elements are added dynamically
    $( "#results" ).on("click", "a", function() {
        // take `text` of a clicked element and set it as `#pickup` value
        $( "#pickup" ).val( $( this ).text() );

        // --MODIFICATION-- Remove all elements except this.
        $("#results").html(this);

        // return false to prevent default action
        return false;
    });
}
...
```

The idea is to substitute the html of the link container (it contains all the links) with the HTML of the clicked link. In essence, it will remove all and leave only the clicked one.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wropgaLt/1/) (without AJAX) that represents the idea. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this link for a working demo. [**Click Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/g0Le1pjs/1/) 
I used **dummy data** and use changed `keyup` event to `focus` for testing you can modify it more (if this helps).

I hope this will help you.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand you. However, if you mean hide result after link clicked, you can use

```
$("#results").slideUp('fast');
```

within onclick event.
Also you can remove other links and live clicked.

```
$("#results").on("click", "a", function() {
    $("#pickup" ).val($(this).text());
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("#results a:not(.selected)").remove();
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Once link has been selected I want to remove other links...see screen shot

Comment: nope that didnt do it...thankyou for contribution though